# Repeated elements in custom ListView even controlling convertView == null

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom ListView which repeat elements. I have tried to control the recycling of elements but I am not sure if I'm doing it properly. That's my code:

```
static class Holder {
    static TextView nombre;
    static TextView direccion;
    static RatingBar ratingBar;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_establecimientos, null);
        holder = new Holder();
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Holder.nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombre_establecimiento);
    Holder.direccion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.direccion_establecimiento);
    Holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarListaEstablecimiento);

    convertView.setTag(holder);

    Holder.nombre.setText(this.establecimientos.get(position).getNombreEstablecimiento());
    Holder.direccion.setText(this.establecimientos.get(position).getNombreVia());
    Holder.ratingBar.setRating(this.establecimientos.get(position).getPuntuacionMedia());

    return convertView;
}
```

My problem is that even taking care of convertView == null (or convertView != null) I have elements repeated multiple times in the ListView. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Using static data seems to be your problem.  There is only one instance of static class members per class.  So change

```
static lass Holder { // all fields are static.  Thus only one instance exists
    static TextView nombre;
    static TextView direccion;
    static RatingBar ratingBar;
}
```

to

```
class Holder { // non-static fields exist in each Holder object instance
    TextView nombre;
    TextView direccion;
    RatingBar ratingBar;
}
```

and change all instances of

```
Holder.property.set...
```

to

```
holder.property.set...
```

Comment: @moictab - I see that your comment about this not working appears to have vanished.  Does that mean this is now working for you?

Comment: I have tried your changes and a few things more, but the issue still happening (thats why I write the comment and deleted it)

Comment: Are you sure that you have re-comnplied and re-deployed the application?  Have you verified that that the data really is different for each item in the list?

Comment: Yep, the list should show 6 elements but it shows 12 (the 6 elements repeated twice, in the same order). Is there any other method or code that I should review?

Comment: What you are describing, does not sound like a problem with your code above.  You have now re-worked you code to work properly with Android view re-cycling. When there is a problem with view recycling, it typically does not present itself the way you describe.  Thus I would start looking at your datasource.  Perhaps somehow your dataset is being duplicated, but that is just a wild guess at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the class like this.

```
private static class Holder {
    private TextView nombre;
    private TextView direccion;
    private RatingBar ratingBar;
}

// And make sure that you use the holder pattern correctly. It has to be for one time binding only. You are binding the views for every getView call. So that is not proper. I think static class is not an issue, because we actually need only one instance of the class.

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        view = View.inflate(context,R.layout.list_item_establecimientos, null);
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        holder.nombre = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_establecimiento);
        holder.direccion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.direccion_establecimiento);
        holder.ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBarListaEstablecimiento);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        view = convertview;
    }

    Holder holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    holder.nombre.setText(this.establecimientos.get(position).getNombreEstablecimiento());
    holder.direccion.setText(this.establecimientos.get(position).getNombreVia());
    holder.ratingBar.setRating(this.establecimientos.get(position).getPuntuacionMedia());

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I'll check if I am using the holder pattern correctly.